# How to add many variables vertically for readability in php

Tags: php, math

I have about 45 different values that I need to add, and to avoid having a really long line of `variable + variable + variable`, I'm looking for a way to add them vertically to make it easier to read.

Only thing I can think of is to load them into an array, but is there a better way?

```
$variable+

$variable+

$variable+

$variable+
```

Comment: Do these variables have similar names?

Comment: Not really. They share the last 6 or 10 characters (two different sets), but the first X letters are different.

Comment: That might be enough.

Comment: If you can't use arrays, then variable variables would help.

Answer (score 7):

Load them all into an array and then use [`array_sum`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-sum.php)

Answer (score 1):

This is pretty dirty, but if you have a common variable name pattern, like the last 6-10 characters as you say.  Then you could do this:

```
$postfixPatterns = array("xxxxxx", "yyyyyy");

$definedVars = get_defined_vars();

$sums = array_combine($postfixPatterns, array_fill(0, count($postfixPatterns), 0));

foreach ($definedVars as $cVarName => $cVar) {
    foreach ($postfixPatterns as $cPattern) {
        if (preg_match("/" . preg_quote($cPattern, "/") . "$/", $cVarName)) {
            $sums[$cVarName] += $cVar;
        }
    }
}

// var_dump($sums); --> array('xxxxxx' => sum of xxxxxx,
//                            'yyyyyy' => sum of yyyyyy);
```

Of course it would be better to refactor the code to store the values in an array in the first place!

Comment: Note it's critically reliant on absolutely no variables having the same postfix letters as any other defined variable.  To make it prefix, just change the first parameter to the `preg_match` call to: `"/^" . preg_quote($cPattern, "/") . "/"`

Answer (score 0):

You can also use this syntax :

```
$sum  = $var1;
$sum += $var2;
$sum += $var3;
...
```